# What is correct way to save Node with RelationshipEntity in Spring Data neo4j?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-neo4j

Actually, I am trying to save one node with RelationshipEntity class as follows:

1. **Node Class**

   ```
   @NodeEntity  
   public class MyEvent  
   {  
        @GraphId  
        private Long nodeId;  
        @RelatedToVia(type = "INVITED_TO")  
        @Fetch Set<EventResponse> eventResponse;  
   }
   ```
2. **RelationshipEntity Class**

   ```
   @RelationshipEntity(type="INVITED_TO")  
   public class EventResponse  implements Serializable   
   {  
      @GraphId  
      Long nodeId;  

      @StartNode  
      MyEvent event;  

      @EndNode  
      User user;  

     //  .....
   ```

   }

When I am trying to save `MyEvent`

```
org.neo4j.graphdb.NotFoundException: '__type__' property not found for RelationshipImpl #153 of type 15 between Node[159] and Node[117].
```

So I guess based on above exception, it missing somewhere `__type__` property which is required to identify any node type. I am not exactly getting, is there any way that we save first relationship entity followed by NodeEntity or viceversa or simultaneously ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **type** property does not need to be set explicitly by you. It is managed by spring-data-neo4j.

The following code snippets work for me:

The event class:

```
@NodeEntity
public class MyEvent
    {

    @GraphId
    private Long       nodeId;

    @RelatedToVia(type = "INVITED_TO")
    @Fetch
    Set<EventResponse> eventResponse;

    }
```

The user class:

```
@NodeEntity
public class User
    {

    @GraphId
    private Long userId;  

    }
```

And the response class:

```
@RelationshipEntity(type = "INVITED_TO")
public class EventResponse
    {

    @GraphId
    private Long    nodeId;

    @StartNode
    MyEvent event;

    @EndNode
    User    user;

    }
```

I use them in a short junit test:

```
@Autowired
    private Neo4jTemplate template;

    @Transactional
    @Test
    public void saveEvent()
        {

        User user = new User();
        MyEvent event = new MyEvent();

        EventResponse response = new EventResponse();
        response.user = user;
        response.event = event;

        this.template.save(user);
        this.template.save(event);
        this.template.save(response);

        }
```

Comment: So is there any significant difference between Neo4jTemplate and Repository class ? because I am trying to save it via repository. another thing is that, User is already present with his own property and relationships, I just need to invite users to MyEvent, it crash.

Comment: AFAIK you can use both the repository and the template for saving nodes/relationships equally. I changed the above sample to use a GraphRepository<EventResponse> and GraphRepository<MyEvent> instead. Both works. Also when the user entity has already been persisted. Just take the loaded user object instance and assign it to response.user. And make sure that you persist the event before you persist the relationship.

Comment: yes it worked.. big thanks for **make sure that you persist the event before you persist the relationship**. The mistake which I did was, saving MyEvent first with EventResponse into it by calling setter.